# I cant get value from path url react.js

Tags: reactjs

I cant get value from path url react.js I want to get id before property-edit url
it show error ..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

error img
[image]

url img

[image]

route

[image]

class
[image]

Comment: is your component wrapped using `withRouter()`?

Comment: @WebbH I just added it, I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD withRouter

```js
import React from "react";
import { firestore } from "../../firebase/firebase.utils";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class Editproperty extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      
      property: [],
    };
  }

  
  componentDidMount() {
    var todos = [];
    console.log(""+this.props.match.params.id)
    firestore
      .collection("house")

      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        let dict = { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
        todos.push(dict);
        this.setState({
            property: todos,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      });
      console.log(this.state.property)
  }
  
  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
 <p>Hello</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Editproperty);
```